# How to generate Oracle Types from object java generated with jaxb?

Tags: java, oracle

I generated java objects from a DTD file with Jaxb and now I would like to send data into a PL/SQL procedure.

To do that, I need to create Oracle types.
Jaxb generated a lot of objects, Is there a solution to generate the SQL to create oracle types ? 
How would you do that ?

Many thanks

Comment: Well the easiest way to write Java objects to a database might be using Hibernate.  But I don't know how that would play in to the work you have already done.

Comment: Your are right, but I have to use JDBC in my case :/